# Out of a sudden my /admin route inside the Auth Middleware in Laravel 8 returns a 404 not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-8

I recently started to code my own Admin panel in Laravel.
Every route was working fine, but all of a sudden the /admin route inside the Auth middleware group stopped working properly.

[This are my routes inside web.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkTfw.png)

[My php artisan route:list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxfp5.png)

And the EntryController@index looks like this:

```
public function index()
{
    //
    $entries = Entry::all();
    return view('admin.index', ['entries' => $entries]);
}
```

I'm having this problem for about 2 now, so maybe one of you know the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're having this issue because of how Laravel prioritises its routes.

And I think the culprit might be this route:

```php
Route::get('/{link}', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

When you use `{link}` you are basically saying: "expect anything in this segment of the URI". Since the `/{link}` route is placed before the `/admin` route, and their URIs both contain only one segment, Laravel will try to resolve `/{link}` first.

Solution: just move the `/{link}` route below the `/admin` route. Might be best to just place it at the bottom of the list :D

Comment: Well, that explains a lot. Thanks for providing me with the solution!